# Using array_splice causes "Undefined Offset"-error

Tags: php, arrays

Good evening guys,

Currently working on a piece of code with arrays that would be deleted if a condition is met. After trying it with array_unset I decided to use array_splice to not destroy the id-structure. Unfortunately I have the same problem:

```
E_NOTICE : type 8 -- Undefined offset: 5 -- at line 59
E_NOTICE : type 8 -- Undefined offset: 5 -- at line 60
```

Offset ranks from 5 to 2.

Explanation: To understand what I am doing here, I give a short explanation. With a given x- and y-coordinate my little program should iterate through the array-elements to find the nearest city from start town. The nearest point would be the new starting point and removed from the cities-array, because it has already been visited. And the whole process starts again until there is no other element left in the cities-array. It's like the travelling-salesman-problem.

Now I'd like to solve it, but I don't know how nor do I understand the problem. I read about using array_values and it didn't work.

```
$cities = array
  (
    (0) => Array(
      ('city') => 'San Francisco',
      ('x_cord') => '22',
      ('y_cord') => '28',
      ),
    (1) => Array(
      ('city') => 'Oakland',
      ('x_cord') => '15',
      ('y_cord') => '13',
      ),
    (2) => Array(
      ('city') => 'Stanford',
      ('x_cord') => '5',
      ('y_cord') => '2',
      ),
    (3) => Array(
      ('city') => 'Palo Alto',
      ('x_cord') => '17',
      ('y_cord') => '15',
      ),
    (4) => Array(
      ('city') => 'San Jose',
      ('x_cord') => '5',
      ('y_cord') => '2',
      ),
    (5) => Array(
      ('city') => 'Marin',
      ('x_cord') => '22',
      ('y_cord') => '28',
      ),
    (6) => Array(
      ('city') => 'Sacramento',
      ('x_cord') => '30',
      ('y_cord') => '40',
      )
);       




$curCit = "San Francisco";
$key = array_search('Oakland', array_column($cities, 'city'));
$curX = $cities[$key]['x_cord']; //3; 
$curY = $cities[$key]['y_cord']; //4;
$hv = 0;
$distance = 0;
$row_city = 0;

$way = array();
$counter = count($cities);
while ($counter>0) {

        for ($i = 5; $i >= 0; $i--) {
            global ${"value_" . $i};
            //${"value_" . $i} = $cities[$i][1]+$cities[$i][2];
            ${"value_" . $i . "x"} = $curX - $cities[$i]['x_cord'];
            ${"value_" . $i . "y"} = $curY - $cities[$i]['y_cord'];
            ${"value_" . $i} = sqrt(${"value_" . $i . "x"}*${"value_" . $i . "x"} + ${"value_" . $i . "y"}*${"value_" . $i . "y"});

            if ( $hv == 0 ) {
                //global $hv;
                $hv = ${"value_" . $i};

            }
            elseif ($hv > 0 ) {



                      if (${"value_" . $i}<$hv) {
                      //global $hv;
                      $hv = ${"value_" . $i};
                      $distance = $distance + $hv;
                      $row_city = $i;
                      $curX = $cities[$i]['x_cord']; //3; 
                      $curY = $cities[$i]['y_cord']; //4;


                               $newdata =  array (
                                      'next_city' => $cities[$i]['city'],
                                      'nxt_cty_xcord' => $cities[$i]['x_cord'],
                                      'nxt_cty_ycord' => $cities[$i]['y_cord'],
                                      'distance' => ${"value_" . $i}
                                    );
                          //array_push($way,$newdata);
      array_push($way,$newdata);
      array_splice($cities, $i);
      $cities = array_values($cities);

                      } //end 2nd if-clause

            echo number_format(${"value_" . $i},2);
            echo " ";
            echo "HV ";
            echo number_format($hv,2);
            echo "<br>";
             $hv = 0;

        } //end 1st if-clause
      } //end for-clause



      $counter--;
} //end while-loop
print_r($cities);
echo "<br>";
print_r($way);
```

The code isn't perfect yet, because I am still working. But the problem with removing an array-element from the cities-multidimensional array stops me.

Can anybody help and give advice?
If you like to recommend array_values, please be son kind and give an example how to it, after I tried it and may have made a mistake.

Thanks in advance.

Edit: though if I position the array_splice behind the variables to which I assign the values would be a solution.

Comment: Suggested Reading: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: The problem is that you're trying to read element from $cities at lines             `${"value_" . $i . "x"} = $curX - $cities[$i]['x_cord'];``${"value_" . $i . "y"} = $curY - $cities[$i]['y_cord'];` that currently does not exist, because it was spliced away with `array_splice($cities, $i);`. Try to explain what do you want to achieve, because there must be better way than this bunch of IFs...

Comment: @HonzaRydrych: Have added an additional explanation in the post. If I need to improve the explanation, please let me know. Maybe it's still not precise enough.
Yes, this is unfortunately the problem, but thought, it would be okay if I position the splice after assign the values to the variables while the script is "working down" from line 1 to xy.
wogsland: sorry =^}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to simplify your code as much as possible according to your description. If something will be unclear, don't hesitate to ask. I omitted the 'next_city' item in the result, because it seems unnecessary (due to same data in the next item), but the code can be easily altered.

Worth to mention those things after reviewing your code:

- try to use variable variables ${xy} only when it's necessary, it's less readable, even for you after a year or two :-)
- when you're dealig with iterables (e.g. arrays) with unclear index, use foreach loop instead of for. You won't come into problems with undefined indexes when you remove items from array.

The final code (without array definition):

```
//for debugging
//var_dump($cities);

$startCity = "San Francisco";

$nearestCityIndex = array_search($startCity, array_column($cities, 'city'));
$hv = null;
$counter = count($cities);
for($c=0; $c < $counter; $c++) {
    //add new item to the route plan array
    $route[] = array_merge(
        $cities[$nearestCityIndex],
        array('distanceFromPrevious' => $hv)
    );

    //remove already planned city from source array
    unset($cities[$nearestCityIndex]);

    //get last one from already planned cities
    $lastItem = $route[count($route)-1];

    $hv = 99999;
    //loop through remaining cities to get shortest possible distance last planned city
    foreach($cities as $key => $item) {
        $tmpDist = sqrt(pow($lastItem['x_cord'] - $item['x_cord'],2) + pow($lastItem['y_cord'] - $item['y_cord'], 2));
        if ($hv >= $tmpDist) {
            $hv = $tmpDist;
            $nearestCityIndex = $key;
        }
    }
}

//for debugging
//echo "<br><br>";
//var_dump($route);
```

Comment: Is this answer helpfull or any explanation needed?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It took a while to understand your solution, but it's a good one, a simple and short one. Your code taught me a lot.